# remove class of all elements inside block

Tags: jquery

In my table some `<td>` elements have class `collapse`. So, I need to remove this class from all elements, which have this class inside my table, clicking on `a-element`.
And then change a tag value to "Hide" and return class `collapse` to the elements which had him before.

```
<a href="#">Show All</a>
<table class="prices">
    <tr>
        <td>$ 100</td>
        <td class="collapse">$ 99</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td class="collapse">$ 99</td>
        <td>$120</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cache the elements that are collapsible, and then toggle the class and the text inside the click handler.

```
var collapsed = $('.collapse');

$('a').on('click', function() {

    collapsed.toggleClass('collapse');

    $(this).text(function(_,txt) {
        return txt === 'Show All' ? 'Hide' : 'Show All';
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".collapse").removeClass("collapse");
```

Ref: http://praba-2011.blogspot.in

Comment: This will just remove the class. The OP need to be able to toggle it back. The OP also needs to change the text in the link.

Comment: Also, the link to what I guess is your personal blog is quite likely to be considered as spam, unless you have it point to a post that's relevant to the question asked.